# React.props.children is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child, children

Im still not quite sure how reacts parents/children work.

I have a component called `quiz` which pulls in my `quizBody` component

```
<div className="quizContainer">
  <h1>{this.props.quizName}</h1>
  <QuizBody
    quizName={this.props.quizName}
    time={this.props.time}
    start={this.startQuiz}
    disabled={this.state.disabled}
    onEnter={this.onEnter}
    handleEnteredValue={this.handleEnteredValue}
    youWon={this.state.youWon}
  />
</div>
```

so I assumed that quiz would be the parent of quizBody? but when I call `this.props.children` in either file. I get undefined? 
can post more code if necessary but just confused as to how children work in react.

Comment: You can think of props as the attributes or properties within a tag and props.children as the content between the tags.  Here your QuizBody doesn't have any content between the tag, so naturally it's undefined or null. In the DOM, the content between the tags is considered a child node.

Comment: basically inside my quizBody component, i have an input box with a ref tag. how can I get access to that ref tag?

Comment: `ref={ref => this.inputRef = ref}`, then elsewhere in `QuizBody` you can refer to `this.inputRef`.

Answer (score 3):

`props.children` is set to the current element's content.

```
<Outer>
  {"hello!"}
</Outer>
```

In this case, `Outer`'s `this.props.children` is`"hello"`.

In your example `this.props.children` is `undefined` in `QuizBody` because the `QuizBody` you created has no content.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following component structure:

```
<Parent>
    <Children />
    <Children />
</Parent>
```

The component Parent has 2 children (Child).

One use case of React.children is as follows:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children);
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.children } 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Child = () => <div>Hello</div>

const Family = () => <Parent>
  <Child/>
  <Child/>
</Parent>

ReactDOM.render(<Family />, 
document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/jmxgp5pp/) to understand how 'children' work.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children.map(child => <div>
            Child: {child}
        </div>)}
        <span>I'm not a child</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <span> I'm {this.props.name} </span>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent>
    <Child name="one" />
    <Child name="two" />
  </Parent>
  ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```